# Functional Integration for complex fields

Tags: homework-and-exercises, field-theory, path-integral

As an exercise i'm trying to compute the following partition function:
$$Z[\phi]=\int{DX e^{{\frac{i}{\hbar}}\int L(X,\phi)}}$$
In this case $L=X(x)^{\dagger}MX(x)+\phi(x)\Gamma^\dagger X$.

M is a hermitian matrix, X is a complex doublet $X=(\chi,\chi^*)^T$, $\Gamma=(\gamma,\gamma^*)^T$, constants and $\phi(x)$ is a real field.

My idea for this calculation is to write the linear term as follows:
$$\phi(x)\Gamma^\dagger X=\frac{1}{2}\phi(x)(\Gamma^\dagger X(x)+X^\dagger 
 (x)\Gamma)$$.
This should allow me to perform the functional integration over the complex field X(x) obtaining something like

$$Z[\phi]=Z[0]e^{-\frac{1}{2}\int{dxdy\phi(x)\Gamma^\dagger}\Delta_F(x-y)\Gamma\phi(y)}$$ where $\Delta_F(x-y)$ is the Feynman propagator, given by the inverse of M.

Do you think this is correct?

Comment: Looks correct. Infact it is given as an exercise at the end of chapter 2 in Negele-Orland. You can (semi) rigorously prove it by changing path integration variables as : $(\chi_{}^{}(x),\chi_{}^{*}(x))$ $\rightarrow$ $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\chi_{}^{}(x)+\chi_{}^{*}(x),i(\chi_{}^{*}(x)-\chi_{}^{}(x)))$.